How to deal with a very perfectionist supervisor whose projects feel never ending and never get submitted?
I am a postbacc RA with several years of experience. I am paid by the PI's grants and there is no time constraints for the projects.
My supervisor is very nice but extremely perfectionistic, causing projects to drag on indefinitely. He admitted the paper was publishable after my first year, but instead of submitting it, he added a new PhD student and we continued to develop the method. After 2.5 more years, with no real improvements, we submitted almost the same method.
My advisor is hands-off and lacks clear improvement ideas, leading to aimless experimentation that prolongs the project. I know the model was saturated after the first year, but my supervisor kept insisting on improvements that weren’t possible. Despite this, 2.5 years later, we submitted the same model.
Our cycle involves testing models without seeing labels to prevent overfitting, but when models perform poorly, my supervisor insists on improvements, leading to parameter-tuning and overfitting anyway. When models perform well, he demands new data and more tests, creating a never-ending cycle. Eventually, the new PhD tuned their models based on test set labels, undermining two years of efforts to prevent data leakage.
I’m burned out and demotivated because it’s very difficult to submit papers under my professor. Despite my hard work, projects never end. I needed publications for my PhD application; if the paper was submitted in my first year, I’d be second author. Now, after 3.75 years, I have one third-author paper. This makes me look unproductive, a red flag for PhD and job applications, potentially ruining my research career as I get older without tangible publications.
What should I do? Should I have pushed more for paper submissions? I fear alienating my supervisor. Should I find another supervisor since our goals for publications don’t align?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Unless you are first or sole author, your options are limited. There is more at stake than your reputation, including that of the other author(s). If they don't think it is ready for publication, then it is likely (not certain) that it isn't and they are perhaps protecting themselves.
What you "should have done" in the past is moot. The clock is unidirectional. But yes, it might have had an effect.
Choosing another supervisor is no guarantee of success, but it is a guarantee of further delay. This paper would almost certainly be closed off from you for future development, though your authorship claim would still hold. But people with more seniority and clout will have the last word on when it is ready.
However, if you maintain good relations with everyone, your admission to a doctoral program can still work out, depending on what they say about you and your likelihood of success in any recommendations. Keep that in mind before you start burning bridges.
Note also that publications are not required for admission to doctoral programs in every venue. In the US, in most fields, they would be unusual. See the canonical question for guidance on admissions various places: How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in Country X?

Even the first authors are burning out because the supervisor doesn't let us submit the paper. We all think it's ready and already have a manuscript. Yes, but I am only a third author in this paper anyway, my supervisor never feels that the paper is ready. Most of their Phd students do not submit their papers in the 4 years of the PhD and some extend the PhD. In the end, the PhD just submitted the paper even when the PI still asked him for some new experiment. What do you mean by burning bridges?

I feel that the PhD is somehow burning bridges with the PI by forcing us to submit the paper. but he gets the first author. If I am also pushy, I will most probably get the second author / cofirst in my second year. I was just waiting and waiting for the PI to submit the paper, but it never happened.. so clearly playing nice doesn't work and impacts my career detrimentally. Yes, publications are not required, but they help tremendously. Now, I have no publication in 4 years, it looks like a red flag and I cannot do research whereas it is only partly my fault.

So you think that maintaining a good relationship with my PI is worth more than publication & authorship? If I can't force them, maybe the best way is to change the supervisor who is hungry to publish?

If you are second or third author on a work another supervisor isn't going to help you publish that. You would start over. Have a chat and ask what you can do to get a publication submitted quickly. Don't make an enemy.

I know, I will change supervisor to the one who is younger and hungry to publish and start over. It's demotivating to never publish a paper here and I am sad about my career..  How will all of these changes if I am the first author?

You want to publish something good, not just something. It may well be that the current supervisor is protecting your reputation as well. Talk to them also about getting into a doctoral program.

I can see what he's trying to do... it's just that his goal doesn't align with mine.. and I feel that this is OK if it is communicated in front so that we have clear expectations. But, the problem is he kept saying we were gonna submit it soon and never submitted it. If I had known this, I would have asked him for a smaller paper that I could submit fast...

Should I do my actual PhD with my advisor @buffy?

Is it my job to keep pushing my PI to get it submitted? Should I take ownership and keep pushing? or is it my PI job? Am I not independent enough by just waiting for my PI?

btw, from https://www.reddit.com/r/AskAcademia/comments/7xkui1/supervisor_refuses_to_publish/, some people say that career is also more important than the relationship and not to let our supervisor hold our career hostage. Which one is more important relationships or publications?

You can try pinning you PI down to a clearer definition of what "publishable" looks like. Try telling them you are keen to get the work published, and you want to make sure you understand what would constitute a publishable version of the paper. Every couple of months, sit down with them and check in on progress, and talk about what still needs doing to publish the paper.
It's not clear from your question if there's currently a concrete draft of a paper. If there isn't, you could ask about working on an outline of the paper to try and solidify everyone's ideas about what will actually be in it.
You may need to be a bit more assertive than you are currently if you want to get something published, although as Buffy's answer says you are limited in what you can do, and it is more important not to alienate your advisor than it is to get this publication.
When you talk to him, keep notes on what he says about what still needs doing for the paper to be publishable ("Okay, so it seems like we still need to do x and then we'll be ready to publish a paper. I'll get started on my part of that and check in on progress in our next meeting."). If he changes the goalposts later, bring it up politely. E.g. "I think previously you said that x analysis would be enough for this to be publishable. Do you feel like spending the extra time on y is worth it for the amount it will improve the paper?" or "Are we in danger of trying to fit too much into one paper? We talked about just including x before, do you think we could publish one paper with that work and then follow it up with another if we do y further work?"
If it seems like the suggestions in the previous paragraph are annoying your PI, then I'd drop it. You can't force them to publish so there's no point causing conflict over it.

Yeah, but do you think doing this will alienate him? If I become more pushy, then he might not like it because he's a perfectionist. How to do this without alienating him? or maybe this is unavoidable since if I am not pushy, I will never get a publication?

Also, my advisor keeps changing the goalpost, so he keeps changing what "publishable" definition looks like.

I think you can push a little bit without being rude - will edit my answer a bit.

There is already a manuscript in my first year, so I honestly thought that the paper was going to be submitted. But, my PI keeps wanting to improve the paper, so it goes on and on. We changed the model and revised the whole manuscript in my second year, but it turns out that's just because the dataset is different (random seed, slightly different codes). In the end, after the paper was rejected, we went back to the original model.

So you think that maintaining a good relationship with my PI is worth more than publication & authorship? If I can't force them, maybe the best way is to change supervisor who is hungry to publish?

btw, from https://www.reddit.com/r/AskAcademia/comments/7xkui1/supervisor_refuses_to_publish/, some people say that career is also more important than the relationship and not to let our supervisor hold our career hostage. Which one is more important relationships or publications?
